# Turtlebot3 stop accepting /cmd_vel command

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot3, velocity, cartographer

I am using Cartographer for Mapping in Turtlebot 3. I've done half mapping and the Turtlebot stop moving the `cmd_vel` is publishing the data but bot is not moving
[image: IMG]

Comment: There isn't really enough information here for us to answer this. Please update your question with more details about any errors you may have seen, if you can confirm that all nodes are still running, your configuration, any relevant networking information, etc.

Comment: What is the state of the nodes? Use [`rqt_graph`](https://roboticsbackend.com/rqt-graph-visualize-and-debug-your-ros-graph/) to check it